# How can we use automatic reloading?

Tags: kotlin, ktor

Trying to utilise the automatic module reloading feature (as described [here](http://ktor.io/application/autoreload.html)), but the documentation is unfortunately not too helpful.

It says to use configuration, but the configuration [page](http://ktor.io/application/configuration.html) is empty.

I believe you can pass in the "watch" list of modules into the `embeddedServer()` call from [this page](http://ktor.io/getting-started.html), but when I do, I get the following exception: `Module function provided as lambda cannot be unlinked for reload`.

So it won't let you pass in a lambda as an application module, but then I'm not sure how to avoid doing that while getting access to the `Application` methods (e.g. `routing()`).

Has anyone been able to get automatic reloading working lately?
If so, how?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Lambda might have a captured state from containing function and thus cannot be reloaded – there is no way to restore the captured state. You have to extract application into a separate function like this:

```
fun Application.module() {
   install(CallLogging)
   install(Routing) {
      get("/") {
        call.respondText("""Hello, world!<br><a href="/bye">Say bye?</a>""", ContentType.Text.Html)
      }
    …
   }
}
```

And then start it with function reference:

```
embeddedServer(Jetty, watchPaths = listOf("embedded"), module = Application::module).start()
```